# Limited Information Maximum Likelihood (LIML) estimation in R?

Tags: r, maximum-likelihood, econometrics, instrumental-variables

Curious whether anyone knows a package, or has written an implementation themselves, for conducting instrumental variables regressions using LIML in R. All of the R packages I have seen for IV regressions seem to resort to 2SLS/GMM as opposed to LIML, which may have more desirable finite sample qualities compared to 2SLS [(Hayashi 2000)](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/6946.html)

For additional context, stata's ivregress command includes options to use LIML estimation, and hoping someone has already implemented something similar in R so I don't have to write it myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a number of ways to motivate the LIML estimator, the primary one being that it is a member of the family of IV estimators known as the $k$-class estimators.

Also, to my knowledge, a direct implementation of the LIML estimator is not available in R (see the [`sem`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sem/index.html) package though).

### $k$-class IV estimators

Consider the linear instrumental variables regression model:
$$
\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{Y}_1 &= \mathbf{Y}_2\boldsymbol{\beta} + \mathbf{Z}_1\boldsymbol{\delta} + \boldsymbol{\varepsilon}\\
&= \mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{\gamma} + \boldsymbol{\varepsilon}\\
\mathbf{Y}_2 &= \mathbf{Z}_1\mathbf{\Pi}_1 + \mathbf{Z}_2\mathbf{\Pi}_2+  \mathbf{V}\\
&= \mathbf{Z}\mathbf{\Pi} +  \mathbf{V}\\
\mathbb{E}(\boldsymbol{\varepsilon} \mid \mathbf{Z}) &= \boldsymbol{0} 
\end{align}
$$
where $\mathbf{Z}_1$ is the matrix of included exogenous covariates, and $\mathbf{Z}_2$ is the matrix of excluded exogenous covariates. $\mathbf{Y}_2$ is the matrix of endogenous covariates.

Then the $k$-class estimators, defined by Theil, can be written as solutions to the set of equations
$$
\mathbf{X}'(\boldsymbol{i}_N - k\mathbf{M}_{\mathbf{Z}})\mathbf{X}\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_{KC} = \mathbf{X}'(\boldsymbol{i}_N - k\mathbf{M}_{\mathbf{Z}})\boldsymbol{Y}
$$
where $\mathbf{M}_{\mathbf{Z}} = \boldsymbol{i}_N - \mathbf{Z}\left(\mathbf{Z}'\mathbf{Z}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{Z}$ is the orthogonal projection matrix. Various choices of $k$ yield special cases, for example, the 2SLS corresponds to $k=1$.

A very crude implementation of a $k$-class estimators in R is as follows:

```
library(foreign)
library(zoo)
library(AER)

#==========================================================
# load and pre-process the data
#==========================================================
download.file(url = 'http://people.stern.nyu.edu/wgreene/Text/tables/TableF4-1.txt', 
              destfile = 'mroz.txt')

# read in the file
dfMroz = read.table('mroz.txt', header = TRUE, skip = 36)
names(dfMroz) = tolower(names(dfMroz))
summary(dfMroz)

#==========================================================
# k-class estimator (example: k = 0.9)
#==========================================================
# 2SLS estimator; to check that the formula is okay
ivreg(log(ww) ~ ax. + I(ax.^2) +  we |
        ax. + I(ax.^2) + kl6 + k618 + wa, data = dfMroz, subset = ww > 0)
# OK

# IV regression formula
formulaMrozKC = as.Formula(log(ww) ~ ax. + I(ax.^2) +  we |
                             ax. + I(ax.^2) + kl6 + k618 + wa)

## get the model matrices
mfMrozKC = model.frame(formulaMrozKC, data = dfMroz, subset = ww > 0)
vY = model.response(mfMrozKC)
mX = model.matrix(formulaMrozKC, data = mfMrozKC, rhs = 1)
mZ = model.matrix(formulaMrozKC, data = mfMrozKC, rhs = 2)

mMZ = diag(428) - mZ %*% solve(t(mZ) %*% mZ) %*% t(mZ)

# k-class estimator (k = 0.9)
dK = 0.9
solve(a = t(mX) %*% (diag(428) - dK*mMZ) %*% mX,
            b =  t(mX) %*% (diag(428) - dK*mMZ) %*% vY, tol = 1e-10)
```

### LIML estimator

The LIML estimator is had by setting $k$ in the $k$-class estimators to be the minimum eigenvalue of the matrix:
$$
\left(\mathbf{Y} \mathbf{M}_{\mathbf{Z}}\mathbf{Y}\right)^{-1/2}\mathbf{Y} \mathbf{M}_{\mathbf{Z}_1}\mathbf{Y} \left(\mathbf{Y} \mathbf{M}_{\mathbf{Z}}\mathbf{Y}\right)^{-1/2}
$$
where $\mathbf{Y} = [\boldsymbol{Y}_1, \mathbf{Y}_2]$. For a detailed discussion, see [Davidson and MacKinnon (2001)](http://qed.econ.queensu.ca/ETM/), pg. 539--.

### R implementation

A very crude implementation of this in R is as follows (no guarantees about numerical efficiency are made):

```
#==========================================================
# LIML estimator (example: k = 0.9)
#==========================================================
# function to compute the inverse square root of a matrix
fnMatSqrtInverse = function(mA) {
  ei = eigen(mA)
  d = ei$values
      d = (d+abs(d))/2
      d2 = 1/sqrt(d)
      d2[d == 0] = 0
      return(ei$vectors %*% diag(d2) %*% t(ei$vectors))
}

mY2 = mX[, setdiff(colnames(mX), colnames(mZ))]
mZ1 = mZ[, intersect(colnames(mX), colnames(mZ))]
mMZ1 = diag(428) - mZ1 %*% solve(t(mZ1) %*% mZ1) %*% t(mZ1)
mYStar = cbind(vY, mY2)

mYZY = t(mYStar) %*% mMZ %*% mYStar
mLeftRight = fnMatSqrtInverse(mYZY)

dK.LIML = sort(eigen(b %*% (t(mYStar) %*% mMZ1 %*% mYStar) %*% b, 
                only.values = TRUE)$values)[1]

# LIML estimator
solve(a = t(mX) %*% (diag(428) - dK.LIML*mMZ) %*% mX,
      b =  t(mX) %*% (diag(428) - dK.LIML*mMZ) %*% vY, tol = 1e-10)
```

The computation of the matrix square root inverse is borrowed from [here](http://www4.stat.ncsu.edu/~li/software/SparseSDR.R).

Comment: Thanks! But I encounter a problem while triying to use the code... what is the b value in: dK.LIML = sort(eigen(b %*% (t(mYStar) ....? Where did you define it? Thanks!

Comment: In `mLeftRight = fnMatSqrtInverse(mYZY)`; `dK.LIML = sort(eigen(b %*% (t(mYStar) %*% mMZ1 %*% mYStar) %*% b, only.values = TRUE)$values)[1]`, `b` should be `mLeftRight`.

Answer (score 2):

I made an implementation of the k-class in a package, currently hosted on github, [RCompAngrist](https://github.com/MatthieuStigler/RCompAngrist) (dedicated to replicate examples in Angrist and Pishke's book). The function kclass() uses the same interface than ivreg, and let to pre-specify k (obtaining OLS, 2SLS, any estim) or estimating it. It seeks to use slightly more efficient computation, mainly through a QR decomposition, but is still under development.

With the actual development version, you can obtain the same results than above:

```
library(devtools)
install_github(repo = "RCompAngrist", username = "MatthieuStigler", subdir = "RcompAngrist")
library(RCompAngrist)

# run example of fg nu
download.file(url = 'http://people.stern.nyu.edu/wgreene/Text/tables/TableF4-1.txt',  destfile = 'mroz.txt')
dfMroz = read.table('mroz.txt', header = TRUE, skip = 36)
names(dfMroz) = tolower(names(dfMroz))

# do subset outside (currently arg subset within kclass does not work well)
dfMroz2 <- subset(dfMroz, ww>0)

# estimate 2SLS (k=1): same results than ivreg (different order though)
kclass(log(ww) ~ ax. + I(ax.^2) +  we |
    ax. + I(ax.^2) + kl6 + k618 + wa, data = dfMroz2,  k=1)

# estimate k-class with k= 0.9
k_0_9_kclass <- kclass(log(ww) ~ ax. + I(ax.^2) +  we |
    ax. + I(ax.^2) + kl6 + k618 + wa, data = dfMroz2,  k=0.9)

## Compare results with code of fg nu
k_0_9_manual <- solve(a = t(mX) %*% (diag(428) - dK*mMZ) %*% mX,
  b =  t(mX) %*% (diag(428) - dK*mMZ) %*% vY, tol = 1e-10)
all.equal(coef(k_0_9_kclass), k_0_9_manual[c(4,1,2,3),1], check.attributes = FALSE)

# obtain k value: leave arg k NULL:
k_0_9_kclass <- kclass(log(ww) ~ ax. + I(ax.^2) +  we |
                     ax. + I(ax.^2) + kl6 + k618 + wa, data = dfMroz2)

# same k than code of fg nu? Could not compare as missing b, to be done soon
```

Answer (score 1):

The R package `ivmodel` implements the LIML estimator ([link here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ivmodel/)).